# C++ running on PIC32 (MIPS32)

Tags: gcc, embedded, g++, microchip, mips32

Unfortunately, my C app for PIC32 needs OO too much and I can't continue doing it in C.

Do you know any MIPS32 C++ compiler for PIC32?

Thanks

Comment: Paste the output of the **file** command being executed on any binary application of this platform.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might contact [Comeau Computing](http://www.comeaucomputing.com/); thier C++ compiler generates C code as an intermediate language so that it can then utilise a platform's existing native C compiler where only a C compiler is available, and therefore porting to new platforms is relatively quick and simple.

For various reasons the intermediate generation and compiler adaptation is not accessible to end users so you will still need Comeau to generate a PIC32/C32 port, but it probably won't take long and hopefully they would amortise the cost over sales to other users.

However if you use Commeau or any other C++ to C translator, you will suffer from the inability to use source-level debugging, and that is likley to be the killer to any attempt to use C++ sucessfully without native debugger support.

Although it is not always pretty, your best bet is probably to learn how to implement OO designs in C. Here's a whole book on the subject: http://www.planetpdf.com/codecuts/pdfs/ooc.pdf

Comment: Good advice, simply write the OO in C. If you think that OO only boils down to virtual inheritage and the class keyword, you don't understand OO. The important parts are modularisation based on functionality, autonomous objects with loose coupling, and private encapsulation. You can do all those things in C.

Answer (score 5):

Microchip's XC32 tool chain now supports C++ since version 1.10

Answer (score 1):

According to this [fairly recent thread on the microchip forums](http://www.microchip.com/forums/m544964.aspx) it looks like C++ support for PIC32 isn't available anywhere yet and isn't a high priority with Microchip. The wisdom of the respondents in that thread appears to be: ***don't hold your breath***.

I'm a MPLAB user myself building small programs so I just take what Microchip gives me. I've never gotten to the point where I thought I needed C++, longed for yes, but never needed. As a next step you can either consider moving to another platform with C++ support or take another look at your design and ask why you need C++ that badly. Some features can be simulated in C with varying amounts of pain and suffering.

Answer (score 1):

You might keep an eye on the proper GCC MIPS port. They have all the pieces, but I don't know if anyone's made C++ work with PIC32 in particular. I know it did work on sgimips.